# How to load my CSS into CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter.I have downloaded a html  template from  net. Then I am trying to load this html pages in view. But the css of my view is not working. How can I load this css in codeigniter so that I can show the  html file when I type `$this->load->view('home.php')`?

Comment: First check you current syntax i.e. view method of codeigniter doesn't require .php extension of the file to be included. You need to write your syntax like this <?php $this->load->view('home')?>

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your css/js/images folder in your codeigniter root directory where your 'applications' and system folder exists.

Then you can access any of the root folder like this in your view or anywhere in your project :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url().'css/style.css'?>">
```

Let me know if you have any further doubts.

Answer (score 0):

to load it. first create a css folder in your codeigniter root folder, and save your style inside that folder, after that use this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" />
```

the base_url is the url you set in `config\config.php` so your syntax in base url is like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
```

but before you use `base_url();` open `config\autoload.php` and copy this code to allow you to use `base_url();`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

hope this will help you. I detailed my info cause your beginner.